# When does weakly elliptic $\Rightarrow$ strongly elliptic?

Tags: reference-request, partial-differential-equations, elliptic-operators

While learning more about the analytic background for the [Atiyah-Singer Index Theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atiyah%E2%80%93Singer_index_theorem), I was curious about the following question (although not needed for the ASID): what are some general conditions which imply that *weakly* elliptic operators are *strongly* elliptic?

---

**Context:** $M$: closed smooth manifold; $E,F\rightarrow M$ smooth, $\mathbb{C}$-vector bundles over $M$; $P:\Gamma(E)\rightarrow \Gamma(F)$.

> **Def. 1:** $P$ is called *weakly elliptic* if, for each $m\in M$ and $\xi\neq 0\in T^{\ast}_mM$, its symbol $\sigma( P)(m,\xi)$ is invertible.
>
> **Def. 2:** $P$ is called *strongly elliptic* if there exists a constant $C>0$ such that
>
> $$ (\sigma( P)(m,\xi)v,v)\geq C\|v \|^2 $$
>
> for all $v\in E$ and $\|\xi\|=1$.

So, again, I'm wondering:

$$ \underline{\textbf{Question:}} \text{ Under what conditions do the above notions coincide?} $$

Or, at least some references?

Comment: The passage from (1) to (2) is the passage from pointwise positivity of $(\sigma( P)(m,\xi)v,v)$  to having a uniform positive lower bound for it. It is possibly under the combination of continuity and compactness. I don't think there is anything else going on.

Comment: @wordsthatendinGRY  Ah, yeah. That sounds reasonable to me. Thanks!